# Loading an avatar using ReadyPlayerMe avatar url in Photon Pun2 Multiplayer environment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, multiplayer, photon-pun

I am beginner in unity/game development. I have start working with ready player me for creating realistic avatar and it works great.

But now I am trying to use this in multiplayer environment with Photon.Pun using provided url in c# but it is not working with Photon.

Can someone please guide me to resolve this problem?

I have also tried to follow this below link in c# which use play maker to resolve this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qu7kYf52JXI&t=907s

But not able to resolve this. I need to resolve this in c#.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code and specify your problem. "Not working" is way too broad.

Comment: In Photon.Pun, we instantiate the prefebs and game object will visible on remote side as well for multiplayer. But in case of ReadyPlayerMe, we load the avatar at runtime so there is no prefeb available, how we can show our avatar to remote side? I am stuck here.